# Building a lazy grid with rows and columns - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, lazyvgrid, lazyhgrid

I am wanting to create a view in my app which acts basically as a table. I believe a lazy grid is the best way to do this in iOS 14, I'm just not sure what I am doing with them. The sort of table I want to create is pictured below:
[image]

Each of the rows are based off of an object, `Player()`, I have and then each one of the numbers in the row are attributes the object has, e.g. `player.tries`, `player.pens` etc.

My attempt so far has been to loop through all players in the array `homeTeam.players` and create a HStack with different text according to the individual value. I am getting stuck then on how I would set each column to be the width I want, such as the Name to be the widest and all others much smaller, but also have the headings above them. My code is below:

```
let layout = [GridItem(.flexible(maximum: 300))]

LazyVGrid(columns: layout){
    HStack{
        Text("Name")
        Spacer()
        Text("T | C | P | DG")
   }
   ForEach(homeTeam.players){ player in
       HStack(spacing: 0){
           Text("player.playerName")
           Spacer()
           Text("\(player.tries) | \(player.convs) | \(player.pens) | \(player.dgs)")
       }
        .padding()
   }
}
```

Any help on getting the sizing and all numbers in the correct place would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a grid view..

```
Section(header: CustomHeaderView()) {
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            ForEach(items){ item in
                HStack {
                    Text("Field 1")
                    
                    Divider()
                    
                    Text("Field 2")
                    // etc
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Rectangle().strokeBorder(Color.black)
    }
```

You can format each field how you like just make sure the header and items are uniform.. you get the picture.